# Img src is using relative path to current url not root of site

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I've got a Springboot thymeleaf project I'm working on.

The page I've got has the following line:

`<img id="global-icon" th:if="${user.isGlobal()}" src="/img/global-icon.png" />`

When this page is loaded, the result is

`<img id="global-icon" src="https://www.example.com/mySubPage/2323/img/global-icon.png" />`

However, I want it to render as:

`<img id="global-icon" src="https://www.example.com/img/global-icon.png" />`

and I'm not understanding why it is trying to pull my image from the subpage as the root.

Comment: I am skeptical. The value of `src` is passed along unprocessed; you are either including a `th` directive that you didn't show here, or what you're showing as "the result" isn't what's being transmitted from your application to the browser.

Comment: I've added a screenshot with Chrome's Dev console showing the error and the page in Intellij with the icons listed on the left.  I've tried with the `@{}` and without it, with `th:src` and with `src`.

Comment: The dev console does not show the source _as delivered from the server_. (The View Source tab would.)

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're saying. (And I'm a doofus.)  With the `th:if` in there, you are correct, the line is *not* being delivered. Take that out and the lines work perfectly as `src="/resources/img/global_icon.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `src="@{/img/global-icon.png}"`

See the [Thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) for more detail.